# Dynamic Images in Email spacing

Tags: html, image, email

I'm building an email in which there will be 3 images that load promo offers each month. Some months there might only be 2 offers and in place of the 3rd image the idea is to just save a 1x1 spacer.gif so a non-developer can just update the promo images.

The problem is that if I don't set a specific height on each of the images, when a spacer.gif is substituted the browser displays it as a gigantic gap, essentially the height becomes the same as the width.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get around this, so there isn't such a huge gap but I don't have to lock a height in there?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<table width="700" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"    border="0" style="min-width:700px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="40" height="1" border="0" style="display:block; outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"/></td>
                    <td>
                    <table width="620" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="min-width:620px">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <!-- Offer 1 -->
                            <a href="" title="Offer" target="_blank"><img src="images/cm_spof_01.gif" width="620" alt="Offer" border="0" style="display:block; outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; font-size:16px; color: #f1f1f1; font-family:arial, sans-serif; height:auto;" /></a>
                            <!-- Offer 2 -->
                            <a href="" title="Offer" target="_blank"><img src="images/cm_spof_02.gif" width="620" alt="Offer" border="0" style="display:block; outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; font-size:16px; color: #f1f1f1; font-family:arial, sans-serif; height:auto;" /></a>
                            <!-- Offer 3 -->
                            <a href="" title="Offer" target="_blank" style="height:auto;"><img src="images/cm_spof_03.gif" width="620" alt="Offer" border="0" style="display:block; outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; font-size:16px; color: #f1f1f1; font-family:arial, sans-serif; height:auto;" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="40" height="1" border="0" style="display:block; outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your 1x1 gif wider like 600x1 instead.

Also, you can leave the height off on all image tags, for example, this is how to create fluid images:

```
<img alt="" src="" width="100%" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
```

Comment: It was so simple I don't know why I didn't see it before. Essentially I didn't need to make the gif any wider. I just removed both height and width and it seems to be testing alright in litmus.